# Access third party flutter app's widget attribute like Accessibility

Tags: flutter, accessibility-api

I am using macOS and working with accessibility part.

Generally, I can use macOS's Accessibility API to get all native app widget's attributes like role/position/size through the AXUIElement tree.

Are there any way to acccess the flutter app widget's attributes like native app?

If there's not, are there any alternative way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: have you seen this page?
https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility

Comment: @Hamed Yep but still get confused ..